# Editing a class file doesn't get reflected in running project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm hacking around with [huginn](https://github.com/cantino/huginn), but for some reason editing Ruby files through NetBeans does not get reflected in the code when I reload the page or otherwise force the code to re-execute; only a `CTRL+C` and a `kill -9` then rerunning the `foreman start` command gets the changes accepted. This takes about 4 minutes on my PC (Windows plus CygWin), so finding a faster method to ensure my changes take would be most welcome.

My `foreman` `Procfile` looks like this:

```
web: bundle exec rails server
schedule: bundle exec rails runner bin/schedule.rb
dj: bundle exec script/delayed_job run
```

And the important gem versions are:

```
bundle (0.0.1)
bundler (1.3.5)
delayed_job_active_record (0.3.3)
delayed_job_web (1.2.0)
rails (3.2.14)
rake (10.1.0)
```

`WEBrick` is:

```
WEBrick 1.3.1
```

And finally `ruby` is:

```
ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15) [i386-cygwin]
```

**UPDATE**: I get the same behaviour with `ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]` with the latests `gem update` versions for everything.

Comment: Do you change directly the code of gem huginn? Or the code's placed in your project folder?

Comment: No, I'm not changing a gem, it's my own project files, in the `app/models` directory.

Comment: I have no idea for your issue, but you can try something: (1) make sure `config.cache_classes = false` in development; (2) see [this reference](https://github.com/intridea/grape/issues/131#issuecomment-10413342), it's about Grape, but may be useful somehow.

Comment: (1) is OK, but how does `rails` know if I am wanting development, test or production? Google search doesn't help me.

Comment: When you run `rails server` it will run in development mode. You can specify mode with `-e` switch. Ex: `bundle exec rails server -e production`

Comment: Thanks, I found that out on Google - I am indeed running development: `Rails 3.2.14 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000` appears on `foreman start`.